# render an empty HTTP response with Grails 3

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-3.1

My goal is to render an HTTP response in a Grails 3.1 controller method that has

- a **given status code** (mostly `204`, but potentially others, like `200`)
- **no `Content-Type`, or `Content-Encoding` headers** (since there is no content, right?)

`render(status: 204)` adds an arbitrary `Content-Type: application/json` header.

Furthermore, this method (see `grails.artefact.controller.support.ResponseRenderer.render()`) in this case invokes **`HttpServletResponse.sendError()`**, though it is not an error. Why is that?

Currently we solve this by dealing with the `response` directly:

```
response.status = statusCode.value()
response.flushBuffer()
```

But this prevents us from using **Grails interceptors** `after` method for doing something before the response is sent. This is why we are looking for a different way, which does not change the HTTP response (like adding a `Content-Type` header).

Comment: Can't you pass `contentType: 'whatever/you-want'` to `render()` as well as the `status`?

Comment: The `render` method ignores the `contentType` property, if no body is passed (e.g. through the `text` property).

Comment: I know this is old but for anyone that has an issue regarding the "The render method ignores the contentType property," from above, the trick is to add an empty `text: ''` in the params passed in the render method. 
Example: `render(contentType: "application/json", text: '', status: HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)`.
This way the contetType will be taken into account.

Answer (score -3):

You can write just like:

```
response.status = 204
render ""
```

This will respond with `Content-Type` header as **text/html;charset=utf-8**. To change the content-type you can make use of Content negotiation in Grails.

To remove the `Content-Type` header completely, you can try `response.setHeader("Content-Type", "")`

Comment: This adds the `Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8` header.